# Nothing in my JFrame appears

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am practicing using GUIs. I have been following a set of instructions however when I try to run the program only an empty frame appears. No information can be seen inside the frame.

here is the code I have:

```
package practice528;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Practice528 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Rectangle Calculator");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(400,300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JLabel lengthL, widthL, areaL, perimeterL;
    lengthL = new JLabel("Enter the length: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    widthL = new JLabel("Enter the width: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    areaL = new JLabel("The area is ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    perimeterL = new JLabel("The perimeter is ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);

    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,2));


    System.out.println();
} //end main
} //end class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the components to the content pane :)

Here is a suggestion using the versatile [MigLayout](http://miglayout.com):

```
JPane panel = (JPanel) frame.getContentPane();
panel.setLayout(new MigLayout("fill, wrap 2", "[right][fill]"));

panel.add(lengthL);
panel.add(new JTextField());
panel.add(widthL);
panel.add(new JTextField());
panel.add(areaL);
panel.add(new JTextField());
panel.add(perimeterL);
panel.add(new JTextField());
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning miglayout. Miglayout really is a nifty time saver.
download it here: http://www.miglayout.com/ and add it to the classpath, or use maven :)

Answer (score 3):

Simple: Don't call `setVisible(true)` on the JFrame *before* adding components to it. Call this only *after* the whole thing has been set up, at least initially.

Answer (score 3):

You should add the components tpo the JFrame by using the following code:

```
frame.getContentPane().add(lengthL);
frame.getContentPane().add(widthL);
frame.getContentPane().add(areaL);
frame.getContentPane().add(perimeterL);
```

Comment: The JFrame's contentPane uses BorderLayout by default, and so this code will show perimeterL, and that's it.

Comment: The posted code in the question sets a LayoutManager, but you are right it's not set to the content pane either...

Answer (score 0):

you need add Jlabels in frame like under given.

```
frame.add(lengthL);
frame.add(widthL);
frame.add(areaL);
frame.add(perimeterL);
```

this only add labels you created if you want another component then create and add it to frame.ex text field.