# trouble with size and positions of components in swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Im making a simple java swing program but i'm having trouble with the size and positions of my components. I have three Jlabels and three JtextFields. The jlabels are overlapping so only the last one i add is showing. The textfields are showing up very small.(almost look like lines.) Also, everything appears on one line and i would like each component on its own line.

CODE:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class setCustoms {
static JPanel panel = new JPanel();
static JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("Settings");

public static void makeWindow(){
    frame2.setVisible(true);
    frame2.add(panel);
    frame2.setBounds(500, 300, 500, 200);

    JLabel app1l = new JLabel("");
    JLabel app2l = new JLabel("");
    JLabel app3l = new JLabel("");
    JLabel site1l = new JLabel("");
    JLabel site2l = new JLabel("");
    JLabel site3l = new JLabel("");

    panel.add(app1l);
    app1l.setText("Set  Application ONE name and path");
    JTextField app1t = new JTextField();
    app1t.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 25);
    app1t.addActionListener(new Action());
    panel.add(app1t);

    panel.add(app2l);
    app1l.setText("Set  Application TWO name and path");
    JTextField app2t = new JTextField();
    app2t.addActionListener(new Action());
    panel.add(app2t);


    panel.add(app3l);
    app1l.setText("Set  Application THREE name and path");
    JTextField app3t = new JTextField();
    app3t.addActionListener(new Action());
    panel.add(app3t);

}
static class Action implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){


    }
}

}
```

EDIT: althoguh i do have code to set bounds for certain items, it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a LayoutManager (A Visual Guide to Layout Managers) to organize your components.

A example with GridLayout:

1) Configure GridLayout in your JFrame

```
// with 3 rows and 2 columns
static JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 2));
```

2) Create and add the elements in order left-to-right-to-down

```
JLabel app1l = new JLabel("");
app1l.setText("Set  Application ONE name and path");
panel.add(app1l);

JTextField app1t = new JTextField();
panel.add(app1t);

// (...)
//keep adding your elements in order
```

3) Pack your JFrame to organize all elements added

```
frame3.pack();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `JPanel` uses a `FlowLayout` by default, this lays out each component next to each in a line.

`setBounds` has no effect as the panel is under the control of a layout manager, which is making it's own decisions about how best to place and size the components

Try using a different layout manager.

Take a look at [Laying out components within a container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details and ideas

Comment: Could you give me an examlpe of a layout manager thatwould be useful to me?

Answer (score 0):

- **Everything appears on one line and i would like each component on its
  own line.**

As MadProgrammer pointed out, the elements appear in a single row because you're not setting the layout manager for `panel`. Following Pedro Vítor's suggestion, you could use a [grid layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html). For example, for a single-column layout you can do:

```
static JPanel panel = new JPanel (new GridLayout (0,1));
```

where `0` indicates no rows and `1` is the number of columns.

- **The jlabels are overlapping**

Take a closer look at your code. What's actually happenning is that you're setting the text only for `app1l` all the time. The other labels are there. It's just that they have no text. Probably the product of copy and paste ;)

- **A note on practices**

As Pedro Vítor mentioned, you should make a habit of adding elements in order. It'll save you headaches when you go back to the code. Additionally, I'd advise you to make the frame visible only after you've added **ALL the components**. Otherwise, it is not guaranteed that all those components will be rendered. Take a look at this question: [Why shouldn't I call setVisible(true) before adding components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790457/why-shouldnt-i-call-setvisibletrue-before-adding-components)

So, taking all into account, your code should look something like this:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class setCustoms {
static JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
static JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("Settings");

public static void main (String[] args){
    JLabel app1l = new JLabel("");
    JLabel app2l = new JLabel("");
    JLabel app3l = new JLabel("");

    app1l.setText("Set  Application ONE name and path");
    panel.add(app1l);
    JTextField app1t = new JTextField();
    app1t.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 25);
    app1t.addActionListener(new Action());
    panel.add(app1t);

    app2l.setText("Set  Application TWO name and path");
    panel.add(app2l);
    JTextField app2t = new JTextField();
    app2t.addActionListener(new Action());
    panel.add(app2t);

    app3l.setText("Set  Application THREE name and path");
    panel.add(app3l);
    JTextField app3t = new JTextField();
    app3t.addActionListener(new Action());
    panel.add(app3t);

    frame2.add(panel);
    frame2.setBounds(500, 300, 500, 200);
    frame2.setVisible(true);   
}

static class Action implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){


    }
}

}
```

Hope that helps.