# JSwing components don't appear until frame is resized

Tags: java, swing, resize, components, frame

bit of an issue.  I'm trying to make a JSwing frame with a label, textfield, and two buttons.  When the routine first runs, the buttons and the textframe are invisible.  When I resize the frame, the buttons and textframe appear, and remain there when I return the frame to its original size.  Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

You should call `setVisible(true)` on your frame after you added the components to get them rendered in your frame. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10790493/3469686) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

After adding the elements, you may want to call [`revalidate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#revalidate()). Post your code for more help.