# Is there an option to add ScrollPane without disabling CardLayout?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a card layout where I switch panels with a button. However, the code (switching panels) works only when lines:

```
    JScrollPane scrPane = new JScrollPane(card1);
    frame.add(scrPane);
```

are removed. In other case, clicking button achieves nothing. Is there an option to keep the scrolling (I need this, since the main application will have a lot of wrapped text) without disabling an option to switch cards?

```
package com.code;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Card {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("App");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(1200, 800);//Give it a size
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
        frame.add(mainPanel);

        JPanel menu = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        JPanel card1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        JPanel card2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

        mainPanel.add(menu, "menu");
        mainPanel.add(card1, "card1");
        mainPanel.add(card2, "card2");

        JLabel l1 = new JLabel("label 1");
        JLabel l2 = new JLabel("label 2");
        card1.add(l1);
        card2.add(l2);
        JButton click = new JButton("Click!");
        menu.add(click);

        JScrollPane scrPane = new JScrollPane(card1);
        frame.add(scrPane);

        click.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout) mainPanel.getLayout();
                cardLayout.show(mainPanel, "card1");
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `JFrame` (its content pane) [uses BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) by default. That means you can have only 1 component at `BorderLayout.CENTER`. When you `frame.add(component)` the default constraints is `BorderLayout.CENTER`.

Now, you `frame.add(mainPanel);` and then `frame.add(scrPane);`. So main panel is removed, since scrPane is being added after it.

Doing `JScrollPane scrPane = new JScrollPane(card1);` it means you add a scrollpane to card1, and not in content pane. I guess that you want it to the content pane (the whole frame). So the fix is to delete `frame.add(mainPanel);` and do the following:

```
JScrollPane scrPane = new JScrollPane(mainPanel);
frame.add(scrPane);
```

Now, the main panel is added to `scrPane` and `scrPane` is added to the frame.

However, your GUI will be empty after that, because you `frame.setVisible(true);` before you are finished adding components to it. Take a look at [Why shouldn't I call setVisible(true) before adding components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790457/why-shouldnt-i-call-setvisibletrue-before-adding-components)

Eventually, full code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("App");

        frame.setSize(1200, 800);//Give it a size
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new CardLayout());

        JPanel menu = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        JPanel card1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        JPanel card2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

        mainPanel.add(menu, "menu");
        mainPanel.add(card1, "card1");
        mainPanel.add(card2, "card2");

        JLabel l1 = new JLabel("label 1");
        JLabel l2 = new JLabel("label 2");
        card1.add(l1);
        card2.add(l2);
        JButton click = new JButton("Click!");
        menu.add(click);

        JScrollPane scrPane = new JScrollPane(mainPanel);
        frame.add(scrPane);

        click.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout) mainPanel.getLayout();
                cardLayout.show(mainPanel, "card1");
            }
        });
        frame.setVisible(true);
    });
}
```

Some good links I suggest you to read are [the Initial Threads](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) and [What does .pack() do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22982295/what-does-pack-do)

Comment: Thanks for the help and thorough explanation! I'll definitely check the links and give them hopefully a successful try.